# Trailing slash in subprojects leads to 404

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

In my routes file, I have the following route defined:

```
GET     /something                           controllers.Application.something
```

If I go to `mysite.com/something`, it works fine, if I go to `mysite.com/something/` I get a **404**.

A solution would be to have two routes, one with the slash and the other without it, but Google won't like this. Another would be to do some sort of redirection in the controllers but it feels a little awkward. Is there some native Play solution that helps doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as a start you can look at https://github.com/mariussoutier/play-trailing-slash - a project that aims at the desired functionality.

You can of course do it yourself. It would go like this:

Put this at the END of your `routes` file (so that it serves as a last resort for unmatched routes):

```
# match every route with slash at the end
GET     /*path/             controllers.Application.ownRedirect(path: String)
```

Then implement the method in your`Application.java`:

```
public static Result ownRedirect(String path) {
    return movedPermanently("/" + path);
}
```